# Want to Authenticate only Superuser

Tags: django

I want want give access to an html file to only the Superuser.
Just how {% if user.is_authenticated %} authenticates all the users including the superusers, is there any way i can only authenticate superusers and not non superusers?

```
{% block title %}base{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Django{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
{% else %}
  <p>You are not logged in</p>
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_superuser %}
```

This statement should return True if a user is superuser and authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_superuser %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/admin" target="_blank"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-1">
  Admin
</button></a>
                </li>
{% endif %}
**This Works Fine**
```

Comment: better add some explanation

Comment: I think every programmer understand this, its very simple but if you dont understand so i can explain u bro, this means if user is authenticated and that user is superuser so admin button is visible only to the admin/superuser

Comment: if you add some explanations your answer will be useful to the OP and everyone who will visit it later and that one can be beginner as well so he will need some